# The problem with a rewind system in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a rewind script in unity and I encounter the following problem. I added the script on several objects, I also added the Rigidbody component on each object, but it works on only one object, the first object, and on the rest it gives the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' considering that Rigidbody is added.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Timebody : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isRewinding = false;

    public float recordTime = 5f;

    List<PointInTime> pointsInTime;

    public GameObject StopRewindButton;

   

    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        pointsInTime = new List<PointInTime>();

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
            StartRewind();
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Return))
            StopRewind();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isRewinding)
            Rewind();
        else
            Record();
    }

    void Rewind()
    {
        if (pointsInTime.Count > 0)
        {
            PointInTime pointInTime = pointsInTime[0];
            transform.position = pointInTime.position;
            transform.rotation = pointInTime.rotation;
            pointsInTime.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        else
        {
            StartRewind();
        }

    }


    void Record()
    {
        if(pointsInTime.Count > Mathf.Round (recordTime / Time.fixedDeltaTime))
            {
            pointsInTime.RemoveAt(pointsInTime.Count - 1);
        }

        pointsInTime.Insert(0, new PointInTime(transform.position, transform.rotation));
    }

     public void StartRewind()
    {
        isRewinding = true;
        rb.isKinematic = true;
        StopRewindButton.SetActive(true);
    }

     public void StopRewind()
    {
        isRewinding = false;
        rb.isKinematic = false;

        StopRewindButton.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error code should have a specific line referenced. This should be immensely helpful narrowing down the issue.

Comment: the line where the error appears is at public void startrewind- rb.iskinematic = true

Comment: so it didnt find a rigid body on the other objects?

Comment: yes, he can't find the rest of the objects

Comment: Could you show the components in the inspector of an erroneous object? Can you also confirm that there aren't any rouge scripts that mess with the rb?

Comment: I created a small video with the problem. As you can see on the red vehicle the rewind works and the error that appears when I press the stop button has nothing to do, but on the blue vehicle when I press the rewind button nothing happens and an rb error appears. https://youtu.be/xXpRa04G57k

Comment: I think it might have something to do with your other cars being initially inactive. Could you test the scene with the blue car active at the start and the red one off? It's a bit wasteful, but for testing could you call `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` at the line right before the error? Unless there is something severely wrong that should "patch" it.

Comment: Even if I start with the first blue car, it does the same thing. I don't have other scripts that interfere with rb. I tried to deactivate the script on the first car, to leave it only on the second one, still in vain, no matter what vehicle I'm on other than the first car, the rewind doesn't work

Comment: I've examined the video more closely. At 0:11 you get an error at line 80, which is the rb call in `StopRewind`. There are also a number of warnings from a different script accessing the rb improperly. This makes me believe that the first car is broken as well. Can you actually rewind a second time? At 0:57 on the other hand you get the error at 73, which is `StartRewind`. Seeing a difference in the error lines makes me believe that an order of execution issue is responsible. Somehow another car script kills the rb reference when you rewind.